# Which is the best way to encode videos into multiple resolutions in django? Should we create a single celery task or to have multiple tasks to encode?

Tags: python, django, django-models, ffmpeg, django-rest-framework

Hey guys Which is the best way to encode videos using ffmpeg into multiple resolutions in django? Should we create a single celery task which encodes the video and save in database or to have multiple tasks to encode video into various resolutions? I am new to all these, so any help regarding the best way is highly appreciated.

I have two tasks here to encode into 480 and 1080p..so is it possible to run both in 1 task or the best way is to encode separately??

Also how does websites like youtube encode?

```
@task(name= 'task_video_encoding_480p')
def task_video_encoding_480p(video_id):
    logger.info('Video Processing started')
    try:
        video = 
        input_file_path = 
        output_file_480p_path = 

        for i in range(1):
            new_video_480p = subprocess.call([ffmpeg, {process},output_file_480p_path])

        if new_video_480p == 0:

            video.save()
            logger.info('Video Processing Finished')
            #video.temp_file.delete()
        else:
            logger.info('Proceesing Failed.') # Just for now

    except:
        raise ValidationError('Something went wrong!')
```

task 2

```
@task(name= 'task_video_encoding_1080p')
def task_video_encoding_1080p(video_id):
    logger.info('Video Processing started')
    try:
        video = 
        input_file_path = 
        output_file_1080p_path = 

        for i in range(1):
            new_video_1080p = subprocess.call([ffmpeg, {process},output_file_1080p_path])

        if new_video_1080p == 0:

            video.save()
            logger.info('Video Processing Finished')
            video.temp_file.delete()
        else:
            logger.info('Proceesing Failed.') # Just for now

    except:
        raise ValidationError('Something went wrong!')
```

Thank you. Highly appreciate the help.

Comment: ffmpeg can encode into multiple resolutions at once, if that's your question.

Comment: Oh. is that so? So how does it saves the final objects in different paths?

Comment: ... provide them to the ffmpeg command.

Comment: Oh..I am sorry! I am quite new to this..so wasn't able to understand you. Do you have any example or any links to the example? Thanks

Comment: Is it like two subprocess call together in the same function? or in 1 subprocess we can encode in multiple resolutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example a [FFmpeg command](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Map) taking one input stream and four output streams could look like this:

```
ffmpegCommand = """/opt/ffmpeg/bin/ffmpeg -y -threads 1 -i '/tmp/dev/built-inputVideo.avi'
  -map '0:v'  -s 640:360 -sn -vcodec h264 -movflags +faststart -strict -2  -threads 1 '/tmp/dev/built-output-640.mp4'
  -map '0:v'  -s 1024:576 -sn -vcodec h264 -movflags +faststart -strict -2   -threads 1 '/tmp/dev/built-output-1024.mp4'
  -map '0:v' -sn        -vf "fps=0.425" -s 640:360  -threads 1 '/tmp/dev/preview/%08d.jpg'
  -map '0:v' -sn -q:v 1 -vf "fps=0.425" -s 1024:576 -threads 1 '/tmp/dev/preview_hires/%02d.jpg'
"""
subprocess.call([ffmpegCommand], ...)
```

Explanation:

1. map command creates a 640:360 video.
2. map command creates a 1024:576 video.
3. map command creates (compressed) thumbnails.
4. map command creates (non-compressed) thumbnails.

**Note:** This might not work for your use-case, you probably need to adjust FFmpeg parameters and provide correct paths.